# Calculate the maximal even cost subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am new to Algorithms and Competitive Programming. I am learning about Dynamic programming and I have a problem as below:

> Given an array with n numbers. Define a sub-array is `a[i, j] = {a[i], a[i + 1], ..., a[j]}`, in other words, elements must be contiguous.
>
> The problem is the find the maximum weight of a sub-array such that
> that weight is an even number.
>
> The input is `2 <= n <= 1000000; -100 <= a[i] <= 100`
>
> Sample test:
>
> 5
>
> -2 1 -4 4 9
>
> Output: 10

For this problem, I can do brute force but with a large value of `n`, I can not do it with the time limit is 1 second. Therefore, I want to change it to Dynamic programming.

I have an idea but I do not know if it works. I think I can divide this problem into two sub-problems. For each element/number, I consider if it is odd/even and then find the largest sum with its corresponding property (odd + odd or even + even to get a even sum). However, that is just what I think and I really need your help.

Comment: Do you want the maximum even sum that could be achieved by any subarray?

Comment: @YashShah Yeah, it just need to be contiguous as definition and it is maximal, the start index or anything else is not important

Comment: Do you know the solution for the more basic problem of the maximum-sum contiguous sub array? The solution for your problem can be found similarly by finding the partial solutions for even and odd sums ending at every entry.

Comment: I don't know what "even sum" is.  I think I understand everything here except what even & odd has to do with it.  I get taking the sum of all the elements in the sub-array, but you wrote a[i] and a[i+1].  So I don't know where "even" plays into it.  I was expecting either every-other-index like a[i] and a[i+2], or something to do with the values themselves being even or odd.  But really your example seems to take the sum of [1, -4, 4, 9] which is 10. Or is it taking the sum of all the odd numbers [1, 9] which is 10?  I don't know what "even" has to do with the question.  Can you explain?

Comment: @Wyck Even sum here means that the SUM IS EVEN not sum of even indexes or even number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is C++ algorithm with `O(n)` time complexity:

```cpp
const int Inf = 1e9;
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    vector<int> inputArray = {-2, 1, -4, 4, 9};

    int minEvenPrefixSum = 0, minOddPrefixSum = Inf;
    bool isOddPrefixSumFound = false;
    int prefixSum = 0, answer = -Inf;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        prefixSum += inputArray[i];
        if(abs(prefixSum) % 2 == 0) {
            answer = max(answer, prefixSum - minEvenPrefixSum);
            minEvenPrefixSum = min(minEvenPrefixSum, prefixSum);
        } else {
            if(isOddPrefixSumFound) {
                answer = max(answer, prefixSum - minOddPrefixSum);
            }
            isOddPrefixSumFound = true;
            minOddPrefixSum = min(minOddPrefixSum, prefixSum);
        }
    }

    if(answer == -Inf) {
        cout << "There is no subarray with even sum";
    } else {
        cout << answer;
    }
}
```

Explanation:
As @nico-schertler mentioned in commentary this task is very similar with more basic problem of the maximum-sum contiguous sub array. How to solve basic task with `O(n)` time complexity you can read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/).

Now let's store not just one value of the minimum prefix sum, but two. One is for minimum even prefix sum, and the other is for minimum odd prefix sum. As a result, when we process the next number, we look at what the value of the prefix sum becomes. If it is even, we try to update the answer using the minimum even value of the prefix sum, in the other case using the minimum odd value of the prefix sum.

Comment: So as I can see in your problem, you do not use anything related to Dynamic programming right?